# Typescript API contract, type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite

Tags: typescript, fastify

I am trying to come up with a simple API contract similar to ts-rest, but strip away a lot of things I don't need. Also I want to use json schema instead of Zod.

Most of the code is copied from ts-rest and modified to my needs.
Everything works as expected on runtime except that I get a possible infinite error from the typescript compiler.

And no matter what I try, I can't fix it. Tried also typescript 5.3 - no luck.

The compiler warning is in this section in the `recursivelyRegisterRoutes` function:

```js
if ("contract" in serverImpl && "routes" in serverImpl) {
  recursivelyRegisterRoutes(
    serverImpl.routes,
    serverImpl.contract,
    fastify
 );
}
```

```js
import type {
  FastifyInstance,
  FastifyPluginAsync,
  RawReplyDefaultExpression,
  RawRequestDefaultExpression,
  RawServerDefault,
  RouteOptions
} from "fastify";
import type { FromSchema, JSONSchema } from "json-schema-to-ts";

type AppRouteCommon = {
  path: string
  params?: JSONSchema
  query?: JSONSchema
  response?: Record<number, JSONSchema>
}

export type AppRouteQuery = AppRouteCommon & {
  method: 'GET'
}

export type AppRouteMutation = AppRouteCommon & {
  method: 'POST' | 'DELETE' | 'PUT' | 'PATCH'
  body?: JSONSchema
}

export type AppRoute = AppRouteQuery | AppRouteMutation
export type AppRouter = {
  [key: string]: AppRouter | AppRoute
}

type AppRouteImplementation<T extends AppRoute> = Omit<
  RouteOptions<
    RawServerDefault,
    RawRequestDefaultExpression,
    RawReplyDefaultExpression,
    {
      Params: T["params"] extends JSONSchema ? FromSchema<T["params"]> : never;
      Querystring: T["query"] extends JSONSchema
        ? FromSchema<T["query"]>
        : never;
      Body: T extends AppRouteMutation
        ? T["body"] extends JSONSchema
          ? FromSchema<T["body"]>
          : never
        : never;
    }
  >,
  "method" | "url"
>;

type RecursiveServerObj<T extends AppRouter> = {
  [TKey in keyof T]: T[TKey] extends AppRouter
    ? InitialisedServer<T[TKey]> | RecursiveServerObj<T[TKey]>
    : T[TKey] extends AppRoute
    ? AppRouteImplementation<T[TKey]>
    : never;
};

type InitialisedServer<TContract extends AppRouter> = {
  contract: TContract;
  routes: RecursiveServerObj<TContract>;
};

export const initServer = <T extends AppRouter>(
  contract: T,
  routes: RecursiveServerObj<T>
): InitialisedServer<T> => ({
  contract,
  routes
});

const recursivelyRegisterRoutes = <T extends AppRouter>(
  serverImpl: RecursiveServerObj<T>,
  contract: T,
  fastify: FastifyInstance
) => {
  if (typeof serverImpl === "object") {
    if ("contract" in serverImpl && "routes" in serverImpl) {
      recursivelyRegisterRoutes(
        serverImpl.routes,
        serverImpl.contract,
        fastify
      );
    } else {
      if (typeof serverImpl["handler"] !== "function") {
        for (const key in serverImpl) {
          recursivelyRegisterRoutes(
            (serverImpl[key] as unknown) as RecursiveServerObj<T>,
            (contract[key] as unknown) as T,
            fastify
          );
        }
      } else {
        const route = (contract as unknown) as AppRoute;

        fastify.route({
          method: route.method,
          url: route.path,
          ...((serverImpl as unknown) as AppRouteImplementation<AppRoute>)
        });
      }
    }
  }
};

export const initPlugin = <T extends AppRouter>(
  server: InitialisedServer<T>
): FastifyPluginAsync => async (fastify) => {
  recursivelyRegisterRoutes(server.routes, server.contract, fastify);
};
```

Here is a working example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-test-infinite-deep-hgtyzj), [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3gKDnAYgQwGcZgAzRASQDtj8qBjFAGmzyJPIAUAbAVwHNgVAIKFEDFjgBK+AO5SUYbogAiKUvl7cYAUQAeYKCkKFgEKpLgz5KAI69jMNRq26DRk2YutrAZRRQAG4BzprallIQvDAoAPJgJOaEmAC+cKRQECBwAEQaxGSIOQDcmKCQsAjIaOh4mSC+9AAWKCD4THAAUr6xAHKNLW1waRlZuQBWhOYAtITNrfjTMBBLhCWYmEiocMJgYJHRKADCWSDmcAC8GKxg+DBNAFxwxFBC-Df4UPgghAD8T90+gMFqx7AFEP8uj1+vM2qwPJAaChIQp6NAACYAHiovBAACMAh1ATDBvgAHypDYoAzQeBbNC7fZRGIARQcUEQlx2ewOMROIDOVDgADJrjgQCh7hB0U8AOQAcR0ABVZZTMNSKnTqtymYcALLRO5eLmM3nHU7nUVYcWSprSuWcWK+FVwAA+cFlKh0ABllTpZW6PZwAKou92yzjCJVHAASqpweOlEIB0OBcJSVJplXpOrNJp5zJQbPBgdNhYNMCN5nVWa12zLhygXOtcAA2gBrFCIJ4vN4AXSeDZiTfdQ5QapzY4o4G4rRQVEriSomKVcGpMSo6MIucLZK5sRAwBgmJ8hfiS8IJ5w0jk-iCIXUYRglhvNjBxFCrn0hmMpnML6sOQFCUVRHy-dxfy8ACW2vOBOE+b5CCeJVWxyW4vh+HI+zXPQNy3KEgVhfA4F+OosjTfAV1Q9DEKwvcnioFBgigUpYJwYsOV7Kh+GQ1CwQ5LCcLw7diQo1g2JIsiGiIqicn4oo+wpCScAYpiAlYtiACEk2QoT53wscKyrKhxLY0iUJyRN0QUvTNxE1MiNMiTSNweoKNkqyFKU5SVLgRjmKc69VOYjScAzHAyUsHIJSldEckDHJeCgbgckwMlSk2bVUSS0xgjvZjYjxcYV1sgyC0bPcrhbVslQAaS7OAhDgTtEAgUg4CVAcOpq+rEGw9d9O3McoFM0jqCPYB8G4YBCBQdF8oCKi6q7RTA2yqBcpQBaoEK4qUOWvrvN8-bev63DBp3Q5RsumJpyUOcF2MpbTqOuBgvU1IMpzcaSCmma5u2lcTgXL56HgAa7JugJKrFOA0RB-AweQ4GYFBmANMyQ4kKsFB6By4A8oCAqiqB8xUcRmB0s+zNNThpJ4CEI9tq5EqIbK3VhzJAAKVh4fJpGOssTGYmx9bNu23aVwpABKJ4fsm6bZvmonFqVSq9y5ls+bRoXC2SFJpYy+HiDgIw8Y2gmUGUBRBGIAIzW3K5WfOyHhu51hZvvKA7u4J4xctiWSbVyxtYp5DLHyDhuzYApyGoWgGHHaXLj3FsyDgLn6Ta54Ve9mdLguK4cggIrcZgHJk5gxr2q5nJQ7B+Kms95ifZFUUcmF4xG6FZuAh9yvArN-HgmtlBbeHB2eZ83u86UAA6TvCAA2CZ59uf6+fQKcEjwpAsN0y0it2bYdg9PM+qbPV5nVCmjodFZygQSAEJC9yUheAYJcK5PtjSGgDPjbwBao1Huud+4-wkkPC2I9EA2xmhPPWU8fLXi5lfJQHYVpwCIHAD+7YqAQFkFQZO2D-aEy9pLYOW82Jcw3hgvqWDty4PwYQ4h24lTL2UjvcgVCcD7x8uFNih9uDHyrrBQBptCxchoWTNGDCcFUDwQQohcixwZR8lwxAC9Cyax4XAGKdoZQSMOHPfR0oOGwSSr7IxMQ563HuOY68c8nFc1QWA-O2CmFKNYVDH2D1FxeExGOMk0sqEG1CteARYVWAZhSBlDUtI6Y0AZlQI8PABBNSdquNmQ1yqcyQTPOWKTfqKwBrnKWmBZYxyjmkwQIgxAMBTgw8Q9AM4aOThcVO8JcbDytrAse8D7aIJnlorGHRhkbw6G00osTMBAA)

**UPDATE**

Just solved it by changing the AppRouteImplementation:

```js
type AppRouteImplementation<T extends AppRoute> = Omit<
  RouteOptions<
    RawServerDefault,
    RawRequestDefaultExpression,
    RawReplyDefaultExpression,
    {
      Params: T['params'] extends infer R ? FromSchema<R extends JSONSchema ? R : never> : never
      Querystring: T['query'] extends infer R ? FromSchema<R extends JSONSchema ? R : never> : never
      Body: T extends AppRouteMutation
        ? T['body'] extends infer R
          ? FromSchema<R extends JSONSchema ? R : never>
          : never
        : never
    }
  >,
  'method' | 'url'
>
```

Comment: Added the necessary code to the question

Comment: Does the question depend on fastify? If so you might want to tag it as such.  If not, please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't involve third party libraries. Ideally you would pare the code down to the smallest amount that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: duplicate of this?  ---- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60265325/using-recursive-type-alias-in-generic-results-in-error